# How to parallel 2 boost converter as positive/negative dual rail power supply?

Tags: boost, dual-supply

I read [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/easy-split-voltage-power-supply-for-analog-circuits-draws-only-720na.html) circuit which can generate positive/negative dual rail power supply with buck converter:

[image]

I'd like do it with boost converter: Converting +5V to +5.5V and -5.5V with 2 boost converter.

I've downloaded [TLV61070A pspice model demo](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slvmdx9)

Official demo circuit is no problem. I tried to modify a little--

make 2 TLV61070A as parallel:

[image]

But result of simulated is very strange:

[image]

Does anybody tell me how to make correct positive/negative dual rail power supply with 2 boost converter? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It requires floating input supply. Yours is grounded.

Remove the ground at V1. If your simulator complains or doesn't converge, connect V1 negative via say 1 megaohm resistor to ground.